# AWK command print number only

Tags: shell, awk, command, jq

I am trying to print just the number with this code, although I get the "XXX,version". Any ideas how I could fix it?

```sh
wget -O - https://bch-chain.api.btc.com/v3/block/latest 2>/dev/null | awk -F ':' '{print $3}'
```

> 613777,"version"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using a proper [json](/questions/tagged/json) parser: [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
curl -s 'https://bch-chain.api.btc.com/v3/block/latest' | jq '.data.height'
```

### output

```
613777
```